# what is the relation between Canvas and Bitmap?

Tags: android

What is the relation between Canvas and Bitmap?

```
Bitmap drawingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(),
bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
canvas = new Canvas(drawingBitmap);
paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, paint);
compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(drawingBitmap);
```

I don't understand this code.Why the drawingBitmap is the composition of bmp1 and bmp2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, the `Canvas` is backed by a `Bitmap`, so when you draw anything using the canvas, the canvas will draw into the `Bitmap` it was created with.  So, when you draw those two bitmaps using the canvas, it's going to composite the bitmaps together and the result will be stored in `drawingBitmap`, as it's backing the canvas.

Anh's analogy is correct-ish, though probably confusing (and over-simplifying, which I'm also doing above) – as I mentioned in a comment, you can think of the `Canvas` as the pen, the `Paint` as a configuration of that pen (e.g., replaceable ink or something - whatever you can fit into the idea of a configurable pen), and the `Bitmap` as the paper you draw onto.  The analogy becomes confusing if you focus too much on the accepted meaning of the words.

Comment: I consider that Paint as a pen and Canvas (that provides methods for drawing to a bitmap) as a hand using that pen to draw

Answer (score 5):

Let's think `canvas` as a pen, and `drawingBitmap` as a paper. You use your pen to draw something on your paper, and you get what you draw.
Technically, you can construct `Canvas` object from `Bitmap` to draw others bitmaps on it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I think the Paint is a pen, not the canvas as a pen!

Comment: Think of the canvas as the pen and the paint as some configuration of the pen, and that analogy might work better for you.

Answer (score 2):

`Canvas` is the place or medium where perfroms/executes the operation of **drawing**, and `Bitmap` is responsible for storing the pixel of the picture you draw.

Comment: Bitmap are close to OS, it is an array of data describing pixels. Canvas is close to what human can see in life like a painting canvas where you can draw a circle or a point, but it doesn't save how this circle pixels will represent in memory (that does bitmap). So, Canvas goes along with Bitmap.