# Draw multiple rectangles on button click on the same canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw a rectangle on button click event horizontally aligned to the previous one. But the problem is: every time button is clicked then in ondraw() method a new canvas is drawn that hides the previously drawn rectangle.Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem. I have applied many solutions but dont work. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to back the canvas with something to keep what you draw, otherwise you need to keep track of prior draw information and redraw.

Usually, canvas is backed by a "drawing" bitmap to keep what was drawn.  See this for more details [what is the relation between Canvas and Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605632/what-is-the-relation-between-canvas-and-bitmap)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will update here after implementing it as bitmap.