# Supported methods on RemoteViews

Tags: android

I am trying to forward values to an Android RemoteView. Some values can be forwarded via the set methods that use reflection. Eg background color works:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.viewId, "setBackgroundColor", 0xffff0000);
```

Although that mechanism looks pretty generic for one param methods calls, it doesn't work for certain methods. Eg. setting the alpha on a view doesn't work (running on api level 15):

```
rv.setFloat(R.id.viewId, "setAlpha", 0.5f);
```

The framework complains at runtime that setAlpha(float) is not supported. Does anybody know why that is the case? What is the rule for supported methods on remote view? Why would't alpha be among them?

**Update:**

The answer from CommonsWare is correct. After some more research it might be interesting for some that ImageView.setAlpha(**int**) is remotable. It only sets the alpha on the image and therefore does not apply to ninepatches etc. But it could be useful for some.

Comment: Great tip about setAlpha(int). It's easy to put a drawable inside an ImageView. In my case I have a drawable containing an XML shape inside an ImageView (src of the ImageView), and setting alpha using an int 0-255 works. This may work for ninepatches as well although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does anybody know why that is the case? What is the rule for supported methods on remote view?

`setBackgroundColor()` has the `@RemotableViewMethod` annotation. `setAlpha()` does not.

> Why would't alpha be among them?

That could be anything from a concrete technical reason to a simple oversight. You are welcome to either file a feature request on http://b.android.com to have that annotation be added in some future version of Android, or perhaps implement it and submit a patch.

Comment: What all methods can one call from setInt/setDouble/setFloat? Im trying to change to translationX of the view. I think this might be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679333/android-notification-remoteview-settranslationx-for-textview

Comment: @summers: They aren't documented, and so will vary by Android release. You would have to hunt through the framework code to see what all has `@RemotableViewMethod` on it.

Comment: Would you know if any setX/translationX methods exist?

Comment: @summers: Based on [the current source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java), neither of those methods have `@RemotableViewMethod` on them. I will be a bit surprised if they want to add those, as that might cause your views to go outside the area designated for your app widget/`Notification`/whatever by the thing that is hosting the views.

Comment: Yep. I saw that too. Is there a way of bypassing it? Or any other solution to translating the items within the view?

Comment: Maybe draw a canvas on top of the RelativeLayout (parent) ; and update items within the canvas?

Comment: @summers: "Is there a way of bypassing it?" -- other than by loading a fresh layout with different margins/padding, not that I can think of. "Maybe draw a canvas on top of the RelativeLayout (parent) ; and update items within the canvas?" -- only if you are going to render that to a `Bitmap` and update the `RemoteViews` with the `Bitmap`. You do not have access to a `Canvas` in `RemoteViews`, as the views themselves are in a different process. All you are doing is describing a limited set of commands to tell the other process what those views should look like.

Comment: What do you mean by loading a fresh layout? How do I do that? Sounds something like redrawing canvas and rendering? So for each increment I redraw all the views.

Comment: "only if you are going to render that to a Bitmap and update the RemoteViews with the Bitmap." How do I do that?

Comment: @summers: [Your `RemoteViews` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#RemoteViews(java.lang.String,%20int)) takes a layout resource as a parameter. Pass in a layout resource that has padding/margins for what you want, for different combinations of padding/margins. This may require you to have hundreds or thousands of layout resources. "How do I do that?" -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6607062/115145