# How do I append text to a TextView in a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing a simple android widget containing only a TextView. This is my AppWidgetProvider code:

```
public class EventsWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.events_widget);

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, "foo");

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

This simply uses `RemoteViews.setTextViewText` to set the text view text to "foo", and works.

But there is no `RemoteViews.appendTextViewText`. What would I do if I want to append "bar" to the text view?

Comment: idk if there is an append. You can always set it to `remoteViews.getText()+" more"`

Comment: My IDE tells me that `remoteViews.getText()` doesn't exist, which appears to be the case: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

Comment: Oops I read the code wrong. How about `remoteViews.setTextViewText R.id.textView, findViewById("textView").getText() + "foo"` Might have to get context of parent view to call findViewById.

Comment: It's not possible to get any data (like Context of the parent view or any View objects) out of RemoteViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you literally can't. While this works:

`remoteViews.setCharSequence(R.id.textView, "setText", charSequence);`

This throws an error.

`remoteViews.setCharSequence(R.id.textView, "append", charSequence);`

Error: `android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.TextView can't use method with RemoteViews: append(interface java.lang.CharSequence)`

Edit: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375522/supported-methods-on-remoteviews) you can only use methods with the `@RemotableViewMethod` annotation.